# How do I add refiners to my site for the Content Search webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part

I figured out two years ago how to add refiners to the Content Search webpart.  I don't remember how.  I put in a ticket with MS and with the company that does our development work.  Neither of them could add refiners either.  Can anyone tell me how to add refiners to the Content Search webpart.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add refiners to my site for the Content Search web part, do the following:

Add Content Search web part and Refinement web part in the same page, then edit Refinement web part, choose Content Search web part as Refinement Target.

[image]